# DevExpress asking to Check Out Winforms when opening in Design Mode

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have an unsolved issue with DevExpress for WinForms.
When I open a WinForm in Design Mode it asks randomly to Check Out and marks the Form as changed even if I am simply opening it.

- If I deny the Check Out it will go on asking dozens of times.
- If I accept the Check Out and I open the xxx.Designer.vb file I can see hundreds of code lines moved from one position to another and object sizes changed automatically.

[image]

Does anyone know a possible solution? It's pretty boring to manage.

*I am using a licensed 17.2.5 version of DevExpress for WinForms and Framework .NET 4.0.*

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't a DevExpress exclusive problem, take a look at:  [How to avoid unnecessary changes in *.designer.cs and *.resx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637122/how-to-avoid-unnecessary-changes-in-designer-cs-and-resx)

Comment: All other forms not having DevExpress don't give any issue... I think some code in the constructor is causing this. Funny that haven't been solved yet. I was hoping in some simple and genial solution.